# Listen to famous-angular scroll view

Tags: famo.us, famous-angular

**Is there a way to listen to a [famous-angular](http://famo.us/angular)'s [fa-scroll-view](http://famo.us/integrations/angular/docs/unstable/api/directive/faScrollView/index.html) for scroll events on touch devices?**

For example, right out of the famous-angular docs:

```
<fa-app ng-controller="ScrollCtrl">
  <!-- fa-scroll-view receives all events from $scope.myEventHandler, and decides how to handle them -->
  <fa-scroll-view fa-pipe-from="myEventHandler">
      <fa-view ng-repeat="view in views">
        <fa-modifier fa-size="[undefined, 160]">
        <!-- All events on fa-surfaces (click, mousewheel) are piped to $scope.myEventHandler -->
           <fa-surface fa-background-color="view.color"
                        fa-pipe-to="myEventHandler">
           </fa-surface>
          </fa-modifier>
      </fa-view>
  </fa-scroll-view>
</fa-app>
```

I can listen to **clicks** on `myEventHandler` with

```
$scope.myEventHandler.on('click', ...)
```

but not **scroll**:

```
$scope.myEventHandler.on('scroll', ...) // doesn't fire
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$famous.find('fa-scroll-view')[0].renderNode.sync.on('start', function(event) { console.log('start'); });
Also has 'update' and 'end' events