# In famous-angular, is there access to scrollview.sync.on(event)?

Tags: famo.us, famous-angular

Right now I have a scrollview with `fa-pipe-from` from the surfaces in it and that works fine, and I've tried a few ways to listen in on the events from the scrollview.

One way was to add a `fa-pipe-to` to the scrollview

```
<fa-scroll-view fa-pipe-from="resultsViewHandler" fa-pipe-to="scrollViewHandler">
```

pointing to event handler

```
$scope.scrollViewHandler = new EventHandler();
```

but no events are coming from this handler

```
$scope.scrollViewHandler.on("start",function( e ){
    console.log( e ); 
}); // is never called
```

I've seen in another stackoverflow - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924752/listen-to-famous-angular-scroll-view) - question which suggested a solution that didn't work:

```
$famous.find('fa-scroll-view')[0].renderNode.sync.on('start', function(event) {
    console.log('start');
});
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

**EDIT:** Apparently `fa-pipe-to` is working as expected, but the scrollview isn't emitting all events. The events that do work are: `onEdge, offEdge, settle, pageChange` and you can use them by piping the scrollview to an empty event handler like described above and listening to these events on it. The events that don't work are: `start, update, end, resize` and unfortunately are the ones I need the most.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I need to listen to scroll start: did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't find a clean solution, but I decided to make a little add-on to famous-angular to be able to directly access the objects. https://github.com/i11ume/famous-object

Comment: Thanks man, I'm going to use it. You should definitely report it in to famous-angular github. It can save a lot of time to many people.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I answered that question in the link

I gave my scrollview an ID

```
<fa-scroll-view id="footer-scrollview" fa-pipe-from="footerScrollHandler"></fa-scroll-view>
```

And was able to listen to the events like so:

```
var scrollView = $famous.find('#footer-scrollview')[0].renderNode,
                scrollViewHandler = scrollView.sync
            ;
            scrollViewHandler.on('start', function(event) {
                console.log('start');
            });
```

'update' and 'end' events worked too. I also used a 2nd scrollview somewhere else in the app (w/ a different ID) and using the same strategy and it worked fine

Comment: I have discovered since the first post that this $famous.find doesn't work when using a router with templates, since all famous.find does it query the DOM, I think it's doing this before the content is rendered.

Comment: are u using ui.router or ngRoute? Using ui.router, I wrapped <div ui-view> within an <fa-view> and in my templated view's controller, was able to use $famous.find on my 2nd fa-scroll-view

Comment: Just tried, unfortunately didn't work. I need to have css animations between routes so I'm putting the fb-app within each template, so I wouldn't be able to wrap the whole thing in a fa-view anyway.

Comment: interesting...sorry can't tell what's going on w/o seeing more code. I also had to decide whether to put fa-app in each view or wrap each view in fa-app. I went w/ the latter 'cuz more fa-apps means more work for famous. Doesn't leave much room for non-famo.us animations or even layouts though. Good luck!

Comment: @jamal If you know how many things will be rendered in your template, you can use $famous.find() after that many deploy events are fired.

Comment: Unfortunately $famous.find() doesn't seem to work on templates rendered through the router at the moment. Which is my current setup.